# Windows HPC Server 2008 R2 + Sharepoint Server 2010 aren't compatible?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint, windows-server, sharepoint-2010

I'm a student, and I need to setup a Sharepoint server (in order to make it easier to collaborate on a group assignment over the holidays). Through MSDNAA I've got copies of Windows HPC Server 2008 R2 and Sharepoint Server 2010 x64, and installed Windows Server onto a spare machine.

When I try to install Sharepoint 2010 on my server it fails, stating that it can't configure the Application Server and IIS roles correctly. I've tried a few things to get it to work:

- I installed IIS myself
- I couldn't find the Application Server role, but Windows 7 is supported, so surely HPC Server can meet the prereqs too...
- Installed a hotfix that apparently fixed some Sharepoint 2010 & Server 2008 R2 issues
- Reviewed the log file and tried to run the command it ran which failed, which stated the command is deprecated and then spat out a list of errors about roles it couldn't configure
- Checked the system requirements (Windows HPC Server 2008 R2 isn't listed in either the compatible or not compatible lists)

Worst case scenario, I can replace the OS with Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 Standard,  Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, or Windows Server 2003. I can also try Sharepoint 2007, although my campus MSDNAA seems to have a corrupted image for download.

Are they compatible, or do I need to download an alternative server OS? If I need a different version, which would be the best option? (I don't need the server to do anything else, apart from maybe hosting a few low traffic static websites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the Hardware and Software requirements [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx), Windows HPC Server is not a supported operating system.

This chap here also has a list of what is and isn't compatible:

> [SharePoint Server 2010 - Operating System Requirements](http://melwaer.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-server-2010-system.html)

From his findings it looks like Windows HPC isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll replace it with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard from Dreamspark.

Answer (score 0):

> [Hardware and software requirements (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx#section4)

Take note that all server are listed as 64 bit, the link should give you the information you need.